# How to do LEFT JOIN with more than 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Currently I am doing this query:

```
select a.x, b.x, c.x
from number as a, customer as b, numbergroup as c
where a.b = b.b and a.c = c.c and c.b = b.b
```

However, I want to retrieve records from table "a" even if "a.c = null", which is not retrieved due to the join between "a" and "c".

I have found information about [`left join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) but I don't know how to do it when the query involves more than two tables like in this case.

Comment: Can't you use two join statements? `SELECT xyz FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b ON xyz = xyz LEFT JOIN table_c ON xyz = xyz` Take a look at the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: You know what this question needs? More duplicate answers ;)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
select a.x, b.x, c.x 
from number as a
left join customer as b on a.b = b.b
left join numbergroup as c on a.c = c.c and c.b = b.b
```

Comment: What if the results from `number` do not have anything in it, but you still need to get the results from `customer`, while still LEFT joining `numbergroup`?  This does not work in that case!