# SQL join 3 tables when no matching records exist on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables - `domains, keywords, comments`

Table `domains` is the "main" one, and all of these tables have common field `domain_id`. I need to write a query which selects records from `domains` table if they do NOT have matching records in other (`keywords` and `comments`) tables.

I have no problems writing a query which selects matching records, but how to achieve the opposite? Looking at [How to do LEFT JOIN with more than 2 tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980052/how-to-do-left-join-with-more-than-2-tables) I wrote a query:

```
SELECT * FROM domains 
LEFT JOIN keywords ON domains.domain_id=keywords.domain_id WHERE keywords.domain_id IS NULL 
LEFT JOIN comments ON domains.domain_id=comments.domain_id WHERE comments.domain_id IS NULL
```

It works partially. It selects records that don't have matches in `keywords` table, but `comments` table is ignored. So, according to other topic I found, wrote this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(domains LEFT JOIN keywords ON domains.domain_id=keywords.domain_id WHERE keywords.domain_id IS NULL) 
LEFT JOIN comments ON domains.domain_id=comments.domain_id WHERE comments.domain_id IS NULL
```

This one didn't work at all (syntax error). How can I modify the query to get the job done? I guess 1st query should be almost OK...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `where` clause after all join like below

If you want to select `domains` which does not exist in either of the two table `keywords` and `comments`, then use `OR` condition in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM domains 
LEFT JOIN keywords ON domains.domain_id=keywords.domain_id 
LEFT JOIN comments ON domains.domain_id=comments.domain_id 
WHERE keywords.domain_id IS NULL 
OR comments.domain_id IS NULL
```

If you want to select the `domains` which does not exist in both the tables `keywords` and `comments`, just replace the `OR` condition in `WHERE` clause to `AND` like below

```
SELECT * FROM domains 
LEFT JOIN keywords ON domains.domain_id=keywords.domain_id 
LEFT JOIN comments ON domains.domain_id=comments.domain_id 
WHERE keywords.domain_id IS NULL 
AND comments.domain_id IS NULL
```